# Google Map not displaying on website. Controls show, but the map itself does not render

Tags: google-maps

The Google map on my site no longer shows up. I can see the zoom in/out slider, map/satellite buttons, etc... but the map itself no longer shows up. I read somewhere that the map should be in a div tag labeled "map" with both height and width stated in the CSS.  The map has always had height/width CSS properties listed, but the ID was labeled differently. I changed the ID to map and corresponding CSS, but the map still will not show up. I read elsewhere that the Google Analytics by Yoast plugin was also causing similar errors. I have disabled all plugins and then one at a time I have reactivated them to see if another plugin might be the issue. However, it seems that none of the plugins running have any effect on the map displaying.

I am a web designer with some HTML/CSS knowledge. I designed this site and had hired a guy to code it into a custom Wordpress theme for me. Like I said, the map had been showing just fine, but no longer does and I have no idea why. I could really use some help to figure this out. I'm trying to learn more about coding so in the future I can debug and fix things like this on my own. A little help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a link to the page with the map: http://seegerlaw.com/contact-us/

Please let me know if you need any other information from me.

Comment: fyi, its better to add the relevant bits of code as part of the question, rather than add a link

Comment: Viewing the source of your page, your Google Maps script does not have an API key. Usually this is required. Currently, you have "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false". Check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Comment: An API key is _not_ required for the v3 API (it is highly recommended, however, as it allows you to monitor usage and purchase additional quota if required).

Answer (score 1):

You're using undocumented fields:

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    codeAddr(function(lat, lng) {
        myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map
        });
    });
}

function codeAddr(callback) {
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results[0].geometry);
            maps_lat = results[0].geometry.location["kb"];
            maps_lng = results[0].geometry.location["lb"];
            callback(maps_lat, maps_lng);
         }
         else {
            console.log("Geocoding failed: " + status);
         }
      });
    }
}
```

Use the `lat()` and `lng()` properties of [`LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) to get their values.

Even better, just pass in the `LatLng` directly from the Geocoder to the MapOptions object:

```
codeAddr(function(latLng) {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        ...
    };
    ...
});

callback(results[0].geometry.location);
```

Even better – it appears that you always geocode the same address – just hardcode the LatLng into your code.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't code this originally and my coding knowledge is minimal. Could you provide some sample code for me with the changes that you have suggested? Also, why would the map previously have worked and then suddenly stopped rendering the map when no changes were ever made to the original code?

Comment: The code stopped working because the code was using undocumented (and therefore unsupported) accessors. I provided sample code. Stack Overflow is not here to write all of your code for you.

Comment: If you read my original post you will see that I am trying to UNDERSTAND and LEARN how to fix this code. I'm not asking you to write my code for me. I asked for a sample so that I could SEE the suggestions you were making, because lets be honest your answer doesn't exactly help anyone who has previously stated they only have minimal HTML/CSS coding knowledge, which clearly this is not. If I wanted someone to write my code for me I would hire someone. If I wanted someone who only cares about flexing their muscles to show everyone how awesome they are then clearly you're the guy for the job.